# Как сделать дилоговое окно?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, javascript, framework

Доброго времени суток. У меня возникла необходимость сделать всплывающее диалоговое окошко при определенном событии. Как будет надежнее: через `appendChild` создавать новый объект `DOM`-дерева, или принести с собой в `DIV`'е у которого `display:none` в стилях? Как поступают в этом случае `фрэймворки`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотря какое всплывающее окошко, если ты делаешь подсказку при наведении, то лучше делать её на сервере, чтобы поисковики индексировали, если оно выступает как обычное модальное окно, к примеру с формой обратной связи, висящее поверх всего и вся, то лучше генерировать из js, так его содержимое не будет отвлекать поисковик.
Тут всё зависит от целей, но лично я отдаю предпочтение js